# Tiling question

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The diagram shows a a way of which a 3 by 10 rectangle can be tiled by 1 by 2 tiles. We count rotations and reflections as different ways of tiling. How many tilings are possible?

I tried brute force and does not really work out.
What is a way to approach this problem?
[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far otherwise they might close your problem :)

Comment: Regarding the approach to the problem, I think you should try out using recurrence relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{2n}$ be the ways to tile $3$ by $2n$, and $B_{2n}$ be the ways to color $3$ by $2n$ with $2$ extra on the column to the left that are adjacent (middle and top, or middle and bottom, not top and bottom).

With $A_{2n}$ case, if we choose the top left to be vertical, then bottom left must be horizontal, giving us $B_{2n-2}$ ways.

If we choose the top left to be horizontal, then for the bottom left, if it's vertical, we have $B_{2n-2}$ again. If it's horizontal, we have $A_{2n-2}$.

So:
$$A_{2n}=2B_{2n-2}+A_{2n-2}$$

Now for $B_{2n}$, if we choose to fill up the $2$ extra tiles vertically, we have $A_{2n}$, if we fill it up horizontally, then the next one must be horizontal as well, giving us $B_{2n-2}$.

Then:
$$B_{2n}=A_{2n}+B_{2n-2}$$

The rest should be easy enough to figure out yourself since $2n$ is only $10$.

Comment: Hi, is there a way that I know when to use recurrence relations in problems? Thank you.